# Are there existing modules to group nodes and give sequential access to them in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I want to be able to select a set of nodes, put those in a specific order (or make them dependent on each other) and give a group of users access to the set. However, I want the nodes to be read sequentially so users cannot start reading node 2 if they have not seen/read node 1.

I would very much like to use existing modules to accomplish this if possible. I have just spent an hour on the Drupal modules site and I'm a bit overwhelmed by the possibilities. I have not found one that does exactly what I want and although it seems possible by combining a few, most require a more in-depth understanding of the module to make a good assessment.

If you have a suggestion for one of my requirements, that would also be very welcome.

Comment: To clarify, would you like a triage / decision tree type functionally? Or is it purely linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For in order reading you should create **story**.
**Organic Group** is good option for your requirements.

Comment: I have switched my accepted answer to this one as OG turns out to be very powerful and is now the basis of my approach. I now setup a OG per group of nodes and together with Views can organize the order of the nodes.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following modules:

- [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views): Views is a powerfull query and report generator. You can filter and sort your nodes or show individual nodes based on any criteria.
- [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules): Rules allows you to take action on a lot of ocations. Let's say you can change data, roles or access rights on nodes when a user sees a node or confirms to have read the contents.
- Fields (built in core): Is a little bit like Access: Create your data structures without coding.

It's very likely that you can do 90%-100% of you requirements with this (and may be some more helper) modules. Sometimes some glue code in a custom module is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I started with your suggestions. For grouping nodes  I found the module [entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) which is great for that and allows you to create a field that references other nodes. I will try to use Organic Groups for access control to the nodes and node groups (thanks @Jayjitraj).